# What is the best way to conditionally add to an immutable collection in Scala?

Tags: scala

I find myself frequently trying to build up Seq's based on some conditionals, but the code I end up with feels verbose and clunky. An example:

```
def generateSeq(foo: Option[String]) = {
  Map("bar" -> "baz") ++ ( if (foo.isDefined) {
      Map("foo" -> foo.get)
    } else {
      Nil
    } )
}
```

If it were Python, I would simply do:

```
def generateObject(foo):
    obj = {}
    obj["bar"] = "baz"
    if foo: obj["foo"] = foo
    return obj
```

Is there a cleaner way to write the Scala code (especially as I add more logic and conditionals involved in building the map)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the fact that `Map() ++ None == Map()` along with `Map() ++ Some((k,v)) == Map((k,v))` and `Option.map` to get the following pattern:

```
def generateObject(foo: Option[String]) = {
  Map("bar" -> "baz") ++ foo.map("foo" -> _)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is completely possible to write your Python code in the same style in Scala, just because you have an immutable collection doesn't mean you can't add elements to it - the syntax just looks differently.

One example to rewrite your function:

```
def generateObject(foo: Option[String]) = {
  var m = Map("bar" -> "baz")
  foo foreach { elem => m += ("foo" -> elem) }
  m
}
```

Another example which doesn't need the `var`:

```
def generateObject(foo: Option[String]) = {
  val m = Map("bar" -> "baz")
  foo map (elem => m + ("foo" -> elem)) getOrElse m
}
```